# The Click event on a PictureBox is firing but no action is performed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, picturebox

I wrote code to paint a toggle button on the `MouseClick` event handled on a `PictureBox` using C# with a Windows Forms application. Here the click event is firing but the action is not being performed. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool flagarrow = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        pictureBox1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(pictureBox1_Paint);  

    }

    void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Point[] arrPoints = new Point[3];

        //Identify rectangle area filled by label.
        Rectangle lblBackground = (sender as Control).ClientRectangle;

        if (false == flagarrow)
        {
            //(x0,y0) for Triangle.
            arrPoints[0].X = lblBackground.Left + 5;

            arrPoints[0].Y = lblBackground.Top + 7;

            //(x1,y1) for Triangle.
            arrPoints[1].X = lblBackground.Left + 5;

            arrPoints[1].Y = lblBackground.Top + 17;

            //(x2,y2) for Triangle.
            arrPoints[2].X = lblBackground.Left + 14;

            arrPoints[2].Y = lblBackground.Top + 12;
        }
        else
        {

            //(x0,y0) for Triangle.
            arrPoints[0].X = lblBackground.Left + 5;

            arrPoints[0].Y = lblBackground.Top + 7;

            //(x1,y1) for Triangle.
            arrPoints[1].X = lblBackground.Left + 15;

            arrPoints[1].Y = lblBackground.Top + 7;

            //(x2,y2) for Triangle.
            arrPoints[2].X = lblBackground.Left + 10;

            arrPoints[2].Y = lblBackground.Top + 16;

        }

        //Fill the Triangle with Black Color. 
        e.Graphics.FillPolygon(Brushes.Black, arrPoints);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (flagarrow == false)
        {
            flagarrow = true;
        }
        else
        {
            flagarrow = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you do the action from temp button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First be sure you are hooking the Click event. I see that this is a partial class so it may be in the designer code behind. Second try invalidating the picture box after they click it to force a refresh.

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (flagarrow == false)
    {
        flagarrow = true;
    }
    else
    {
        flagarrow = false;
    }

    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Winforms has no reason to do anything special just because you changed a private field in your code.  You have to tell it that conditions you use in the Paint event handler changed and a new paint is required.  Make your Click event handler look like this:

```
 flagarrow = !flagarrow;
 pictureBox1.Invalidate();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `PictureBox.Click` event is indeed being raised, and I suspect that the code in your event handler is running exactly as expected.

The problem is, all you do inside that event handler method is set the value of a variable (`flagarrow`). **You haven't done anything that would cause the `PictureBox` control to repaint itself.** Its `Paint` event is never triggered and thus its appearance remains unchanged.

**The fix is simple: toss in a call to the [`Invalidate` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx).** That will force the `PictureBox` control to redraw itself. And while we're at it, you might as well clean up your code a little.

Modify the code in your `Click` event handler as follows:

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    flagarrow = !flagarrow;
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: @Joe: No, you're right. It actually does work. I'm clearly trying to do *way* too many things at a time here. I approved your edit, but it takes two people. And your pending edit is blocking me from making the change myself. So hopefully it'll get a second thumbs up soon. But thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You ought to bring this up at meta, a pending edit approval shouldn't block you from editing your post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just modify the picturebox click event as follows :

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            if (flagarrow == false)
            { 
                flagarrow = true; 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                flagarrow = false;
            }
            //Add this following line to repaint the picture box.
            pictureBox1.Refresh();

}
```